# Kendo format error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am beginning to use javascript along with Kendo ui and I am attempting to format the data in a textbox to allow 3 decimal places.  I am receiving a runtime error of "Invalid character".

The line of code is:

```
$(“#StartWeight”).data(“kendoNumericTextBox”).format(“#.####”);
```

StartWeight is the ID of the textbox on the page with data-role of "numerictextbox".

Is this not a valid method of formatting?  Can someone please point out my mistake?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using some other than quotation marks (") in place of quotation marks and the JavaScript parser can't recognize those as quotation marks. To fix it, just replace your line with this

```
$("#StartWeight").data("kendoNumericTextBox").format("#.####");
```

which has the right marks.